# how to set the length of hanning window

Tags: matlab, window, filtering

I have a time series of data in 6-hour interval.  I want to low-pass filter the data using hanning window with a cutoff period of 36h.

The corresponding matlab code is:

```
data=read('file');   % read data from a file
hwin=hanning(L);     % generate hanning window
hwin=hwin/sum(hwin); % normalize
data_filtered=conv(data,hwin,'same');  % filtering
```

Now my question is how to set the parameter L to get my required result.  Does L means Full Width at Half Maximum (FWHM)?  What does L mean when applying it to 6-hour interval data?

Comment: What does _"in 6-hour interval"_ mean? Is it the time interval between samples or is it the total time period in which the samples have been obtained? What is a "cut-off period", is it related to a cut-off frequency?

Answer (score 0):

`L` is `N+1`, beein hanning window defined from 0 to N.

[image]

Is the equation.
Let's say that `N` (or `L`) gives you the precision of the window, the amount of points it has.
source: [hann function matlab](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/signal/ref/hann.html)

PD: you may be refering [Hamming function in matlab](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/signal/ref/hamming.html) instead

**EDIT:** This may not be the solution you are looking for but I'll leave it here for the info, it may be interesting for you.

Comment: Perhaps this provides useful info, but it doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: @EitanT the question was what L is, and what L is has been explained. What L to use is up to him, once understood what it is.

Comment: I differ. From the question I infer that the real goal is to set `L` so that the data is low-pass filtered according to certain requirements.

Comment: I find that using larger L would yield a smoother result in practice.  So L must have some relationship with the cutoff period besides the precision of the window...

Comment: @MiniUFO yeah you are rigth, there is relatiship between cutting frequanzy and amount of points, but I can't help you as I don't remeber much about FIR filters. Sorry

Comment: @MiniUFO something like fc=1/(2*pi*N), could be.

Comment: Larger L requires more time doing the filtering but reduces the transition bandwidth.  It seems that L has nothing to do with the cutoff frequency fs from here: [link](http://www.dspguide.com/ch16/2.htm)

Comment: @MiniUFO yeah, in the equation Ig ave you fc meant cuttof frequenzy. still not sure if correct

Answer (score 0):

*Hamming*

```
N = (int)Math.ceil(3.3/NormalizedDeltaFreq);
```

with spanish example:

http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dise%C3%B1o_de_Filtros_de_Respuesta_Finita_al_Impulso#C.C3.A1lculo_de_Coeficientes